# ReferenceError: message is not defined. Discord Bot error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get this error when I try to run my code ReferenceError: message is not defined

```
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Diego M\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:14:1)
at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Diego M\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:33:18)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Diego M\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Diego M\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:350:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Diego M\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Diego M\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Diego M\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Diego M\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1022:20)
```

```
const {
  Client,
  Intents
} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
});
const prefix = '!';

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Im Ready!");
});
client.on('message', messageCreate => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong');
  }
});

client.login("Token");
```

Comment: `messageCreate` should be `message` or vice versa.

Comment: I get this when i do message (node:16792) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: That means you should use `client.on("messageCreate", message =>`

Comment: Now i dont get an error but my command doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are not providing the proper event and the parameter to the function. `'messageCreate'` is an event which emits whenever a message is created and followed by a parameter. Have a look [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate)

The code should look like this:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});
const prefix = '!';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Im Ready!');
});
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong');
  }
});

client.login('Token');
```

Comment: idk if something wrong with my computer but it doesnt work i copied the code exactly

Comment: What is the error you get @DiegoM?

Comment: i dont get an error but the command doesnt work

Comment: Check with the bot permissions in developer portal. @DiegoM